# SF story about a blood-drinking but harmless alien and a boy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I remember to have read as a child a story where an alien being, I guess being left behind by his friends, is wounded and has to hide, maybe in the attic of a house. His kind of aliens are being persecuted by the humans because they use blood as food that they drink directly from other organisms without killing them (vampire-like). A boy knows that the alien is hiding in the attic and though he is afraid, he helps him by letting him drink his blood. The alien is portrayed as a harmless, friendly creature. It is possible that they communicate telepathically, not sure.

Comment: I don't want to spoiler too much, but: everybody is incredibly panicked but ignorant, and the boy as well as the alien are saved by an old wise man?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the book again. The story is by [Thomas N. Scortia](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1476), and the German translation I read is titled "Der Fremdling" ("the stranger", or "the alien"), but I wasn't able to find out the original title or publication year.

Edit based on the comments: the original title appears to be "Blood brother", published in 1974.

Comment: There is a 1974 Scortia story called Blood Brother, based on the title alone that could be it.  Published in a Roger Elwood anthology that year called Future Kin, and reprinted in a Reader's Digest anthology in 1977.  Data from isfdb.com

Comment: I did find a couple sites-- like [this one](http://www.worldcat.org/title/reise-in-die-unendlichkeit-science-fiction-geschichten/oclc/213451887) -scroll to the line reading "Contents"- that show the German translation of "Blood Brothers" as "Der Fremdling".

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat reminiscent of Hal Clement's "Assumption Unjustified" in which a benevolent blood drinking alien feeds on a young boy. Differences are that the aliens are unknown to the humans and the boy's donation is not voluntary.